# "Svelte for VS Code" with Prettier deletes commented code

Tags: visual-studio-code, svelte, prettier

I installed [Svelte for VS Code](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/blob/HEAD/docs/README.md). When I saved .svelte file all comments get deleted. This does not happen for .html, .js or .jsx files. I also use this [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) plugin. Sometimes I just want to temporarily comment them. How do I disable this feature?

Below is the markup and vs-config

```
<div
  on:mouseup={event => {
    // console.log('This line gets deleted on save for .svelte file');
  }} />
```

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Light+",
    "workbench.editor.enablePreviewFromQuickOpen": false,
    "workbench.editor.enablePreview": false,
    "prettier.singleQuote": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    },
    "prettier.printWidth": 80,
    "json.schemas": [
    
    ],
    "editor.tabSize": 2
}
```

Comment: Could you please post an example code? I cannot reproduce this.

Comment: added more detail

Comment: I cannot reproduce this given your code snippet. Did you add`prettier-plugin-svelte` to your `package.json`? If yes, is it the latest version?